# Anaconda 3.5 installation in linux mint 18.2

Tags: linux, anaconda, linux-mint

I was trying to install anaconda in linux mint 18.2. I am getting the following error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" . How to resolve this. These are the lines in the terminal

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/styne/anaconda3
  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below
[/home/styne/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/styne/anaconda3
installing: python-3.6.2-0 ...
Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-ppc64le.sh: line 337: /home/styne/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.2-0/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: What was in the last line you cut out of the print? And why did you take a print instead of copying the text?

Comment: Last line is "cannot execute binary file : Exec format error"

Comment: Are you running on an x86 platform?

Comment: no, in x64 platform. I recently upgraded into Linux mint 18.2. Is this can be a OS related issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install the wrong version of Anaconda.

For simplicity sake, x86 is essentially x64. Neither of them are ppc64 which you can read more about here: [ppc64 wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppc64).

The ppc64 version of anaconda won't work. Use this one instead [Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh)